# Is there anyway to get the query ID and status using Athena JDBC driver?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-athena

Is there anyway to get the `Athena query ID` for a query I submit Athena JDBC driver?  Any API calls to the status of a Query (with its query ID?)
Any way to get the query history via API call?

Answer (score 3):

I am using the following piece of code to retrieve the query id:

```
AthenaResultSet rs = (AthenaResultSet) statement.executeQuery(query);
Object queryId = ((AthenaStatementClient)rs.getClient()).getQueryExecutionId();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to register the query IDS such as log messages. Those messages will be stored in a log file that you may specify while connecting with the JDBC driver.

[The log_path attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4O8t.png)

ref [Offical Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html)

Comment: Yes I see the query id in the logs.  For my use case I wish it was available in my application code.  Their JAR obviously has the id to log.

Comment: Perhaps this may inspire you : https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthenaJDBC/pull/10

Comment: btw, i confirmed i can get the query id using setting the `log_path` attribute with `log_level` set to `INFO`.

Comment: yes so the really cool part of this is that I don't need to process any of the jdbc result set locally, i can just run the query, and use a (s3 triggered) lambda function to trigger once the resulting csv file is created in the staging directory.

Answer (score 2):

just to add my 2 cents and complete the answer. The question was to get the ID and the status of the query. To get the ID I used the example [ListQueryExecutionsExample.java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/java/example_code/athena/src/main/java/aws/example/athena/ListQueryExecutionsExample.java) from the was docs. But to get the complete status of the query you can retrieve the [QueryExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_QueryExecution.html) object that contains the [QueryExecutionStatus](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_QueryExecutionStatus.html). This example below retrieves more detailed information:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthena;
import com.amazonaws.services.athena.model.BatchGetQueryExecutionRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.athena.model.BatchGetQueryExecutionResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.athena.model.ListQueryExecutionsRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.athena.model.ListQueryExecutionsResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.athena.model.QueryExecution;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class ListQueryExecutionsExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Build an Athena client
        AthenaClientFactory factory = new AthenaClientFactory();
        AmazonAthena athenaClient = factory.createClient();

        // Build the request
        ListQueryExecutionsRequest listQueryExecutionsRequest = new ListQueryExecutionsRequest();

        // Get the list results.
        ListQueryExecutionsResult listQueryExecutionsResult =
            athenaClient.listQueryExecutions(listQueryExecutionsRequest);

        // Process the results.
        boolean hasMoreResults = true;
        while (hasMoreResults) {
            List<String> queryExecutionIds = listQueryExecutionsResult.getQueryExecutionIds();
            // System.out.println(queryExecutionIds);

            BatchGetQueryExecutionRequest batchGetQueryExecutionRequest =
                new BatchGetQueryExecutionRequest().withQueryExecutionIds(queryExecutionIds);
            BatchGetQueryExecutionResult batchGetQueryExecutionResult =
                athenaClient.batchGetQueryExecution(batchGetQueryExecutionRequest);
            // QueryExecution has all detail information about the queries.
            List<QueryExecution> queryExecutionList = batchGetQueryExecutionResult.getQueryExecutions();
            queryExecutionList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

            //If nextToken is not null, then there are more results. Get the next page of results.
            if (listQueryExecutionsResult.getNextToken() != null) {
                listQueryExecutionsResult = athenaClient.listQueryExecutions(
                    listQueryExecutionsRequest.withNextToken(listQueryExecutionsResult.getNextToken()));
            } else {
                hasMoreResults = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the JDBC driver (SimbaAthenaJDBC_2.0.13) you can do this:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table");
String queryId = stmt.unwrap(IStatementQueryInfoProvider.class).getQueryId();
```